# How do I distribute threads among different samples?

Tags: jmeter

I have defined 100 users in a thread group with a ramp up time of 1 sec. Now, I want to distribute those 100 users among different requests.

Say, I have 2 HTTP request samplers. I want 50 users to carry out sampler1 (first HTTP request) and another 50 users to carry out sampler2 (second HTTP request).

How would I do it using JMeter?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot distribute a single Thread Group among several samplers.

If you want to assign 50 users each to 2 different samplers you will have to use 2 different Thread Groups. Configure the number of threads as 50 in both. Then add one sampler in each of those Thread Group.

You can add more than one Thread Group in one Test Plan.

Answer (score -1):

Please take 2 thread group for 2 request sampler. Set for both 50 - 50 user. Also if you want to do some real load testing then set Ramp-up period at least 5 to 15 minutes.